# re.search( ): (\d+) matches only a single digit

Tags: regex

I want to parse the value 387 KB/s from the string:

```
str1 = '2015-07-02 02:05:02 (387 KB/s)'
```

The regular expression I have written for it is this:

```
mbps = re.search('\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ .*(\d+) (.*/s)',str1)
var = mbps.group(1)
```

Printing `var` gives me only `7` instead of `387` i.e. it matches only a single digit.

Please suggest how can I get the complete number i.e. `387?`

Thanks.

Comment: it will match the 'minimum match' first, your .* is eating the first two digits..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `.*` is greedy (matching as much as it can) and it can also match digits, so it matches `(38`, leaving only `7` for the `\d+` (which, since it has successfully matched, sees no reason to expand its match).

One possible solution would be to make the quantifier lazy:

```
mbps = re.search(r'\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ .*?(\d+) (.*/s)',str1)
```

A better solution would be more specific, for example disallowing digits:

```
mbps = re.search(r'\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ [^\d]*(\d+) (.*/s)',str1)
```

Also, always use raw strings with regexes.